# Why is the time complexity O(n^2) in this code?

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I just didn't get it, why the time complexity is O(n^2) instead of O(n*logn)?
The second loop is incrementing 2 each time so isn't it O(logn)?

```
void f3(int n){
  int i,j,s=100;
  int* ar = (int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    s=0;
    for(j=0; j<n; j+=2){
      s+=j;
      printf("%d\n", s);
  }
  free(ar);
}
```

Comment: If you were _multiplying_ by two on each iteration, it would be O(n log n). Maybe that's what you were confusing it with?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, I know the defference

Comment: O-notation ignores constant multipliers. N\*N/2 is still O(N\*N). N\*N/1000 is still O(N\*N). You only get N\*log(N) if the inner loop only runs (log(N)) times; for example, if it runs twice for N of 100, 3 times for N of 1000, and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By incrementing by two, rather than one, you're doing the following `N*N*(1/2)`. With big(O) notation, you don't care about the constant, so it's still N*N. This is because big(O) notation reference the complexity of the growth of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Outer loop will execute for n times and for each outer loop iteration inner loop will execute for n/2 times because j +=2

Order = n×n/2 = n^2/2 =O(n^2) because constant doesn't affect run time for large n

Answer (score -1):

There is an increment of 2 so loop will runs for n/2. So the complexity will be n*n/2.

If increment happened in GP like 2